# Cannot generate output(for loops)

Tags: java

I am trying to print

```
****1
***22
**333
*4444
55555
```

As i am a beginner in java.I just print

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
```

My solution:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
    for(int j = 1 ; j <= 5 ; j++){
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and

```
****
***
**
*
```

My solution:

```
 for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
     for(int j=1;j<=5-i;j++){
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

I tried merging them together but i have no idea how to do so.I know i am rather close but i am stuck here.

Comment: You are close, you would need two inner loops, one for stars and one for digits. Come on, you can do it yourself! :D HINT: on every line you need to print 5-i stars followed by "i" times digit "i"

Comment: As a hint, try to modify your program to print the numbers, so that the first line has 1 of 1, and 2nd line has 2 of 2, etc...

Comment: Or an `if` inside the inner loop.

Comment: That's an algorithm problem rather than a programming one - your code shows that you know the necessary Java! Sit down again with a piece of paper and write down those lines, while imagining you are a computer that keeps track of some counters while doing so.

Comment: You can try somthing with if then else. j<=5-1 then * else i

Comment: Just to clarify my doubts.Since i need to have 2 inner loops.One for stars and another for digits.The first inner loop,i will be printing stars first right?

Comment: @user2098510 Yup, since it's stars you want printed first.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand the problem before trying to solve it.
In your case,

- there are two loops because you have columns and lines
- the loop that generates the columns:

  - must be inside the one that generates the lines
  - must know whether to print a star or a number
- the loop that generates the lines

  - must know which number should be printed on that line
  - must know how many stars should be printed on that line

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do this.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 5; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        System.out.print(i);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int k = 4;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
            System.out.println(); 
            for(int j = 1 ; j <= 5 ; j++){
               if(j<=k){
                  System.out.print("*"); 
               }else{
                  System.out.print(i);
                  k--;
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just providing the code for this sort of a simple problem won't teach the guy anything.

Answer (score -3):

You should understand what i,j variable represent.Find the law，you will easy to tackle this problem.

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=5-i;j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (int j=5-i+1;j<=5;j++){
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Just providing the code for this sort of a simple problem won't teach the guy anything.

Comment: Normally I'd advocate brief code based answers, but not when it's a basic question the user is struggling with - they'll never learn if they're just provided with the solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
       int k = 4;

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
            System.out.println(); 
            for(int j = 0 ; j <= 4 ; j++){
               if(j<k){
                  System.out.print("*"); 
               }else{
                  System.out.print(i);
                  if(j==4){
                      k--;
                  }
               }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Just providing the code for this sort of a simple problem won't teach the guy anything.

Comment: I don't understand why I got minuses , even if i got the same output required, weird!!!

Comment: he does't want to lean , he wants to get an A in his class. if i were him I would spend some time before posting it.

Comment: (1) This seems like a question from someone who DOES want to learn. (2) If you think otherwise, then it's even worse that you simply provided a code-only answer. (3) Your solution is not even particularly great, the extra variable `k` is unnecessary, makes the code less readable and may help introducing bugs when you extend the algorithm as it depends on another hardcoded value.